# JVM hung on exit with all threads in BLOCKED state

Tags: java, jvm, activemq-classic, application-shutdown, introscope

My application closes out just fine but the JVM never exits.  I notice all threads show up as STATE = BLOCKED.  ActiveMQ failover protocol potentially blocking indefinitely, but the thread dump does not seem to indicate that at all.  The one other outlier is a thread that appears to be from a CA Wiley tool (Introscope) that is in the IN_NATIVE state.

Any ideas what could cause this behavior?

[Thread dump can be found here](https://gist.github.com/cwash/1a7f054a2e1029e747b6).

Comment: Something like `synchronized(this) { while(true); }` could cause that

Comment: @gerrytan - wouldn't that show up in my thread dump?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the relevant stack trace:

> java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(java.io.FileDescriptor, byte[],
>   int, int, int) @bci=0 (Interpreted frame)
>    - java.net.SocketInputStream.read(byte[], int, int, int) @bci=87, line=152 (Interpreted frame)
>    - java.net.SocketInputStream.read(byte[], int, int) @bci=11, line=122 (Interpreted frame)
>    - com.wily.util.io.NonSyncBufferedInputStream.fill() @bci=14, line=54 (Interpreted frame)
>    - com.wily.util.io.NonSyncBufferedInputStream.read() @bci=12, line=79 (Compiled frame)
>    - java.io.FilterInputStream.read() @bci=4, line=83 (Compiled frame)
>    - com.wily.util.io.EncryptInputStream.read() @bci=1, line=64 (Compiled frame)
>    - com.wily.org.apache.commons.io.input.ProxyInputStream.read() @bci=4, line=49 (Compiled frame)
>    - com.wily.org.apache.commons.io.input.CountingInputStream.read() @bci=1, line=70 (Compiled frame)
>    - java.io.DataInputStream.readInt() @bci=4, line=387 (Interpreted frame)
>    - com.wily.isengard.postofficehub.link.v1.IsengardObjectInputStream.readInt()
>   @bci=4, line=1295 (Interpreted frame)
>    - com.wily.isengard.postofficehub.link.v1.IsengardObjectInputStream.setUpStartObjectGraph()
>   @bci=5, line=460 (Interpreted frame)
>    - com.wily.isengard.postofficehub.link.v1.IsengardObjectInputStream.readObject()
>   @bci=8, line=258 (Interpreted frame)
>    - com.wily.isengard.postofficehub.link.v1.IncomingMessageDeliveryTask.deliverNextMessage(boolean)
>   @bci=54, line=76 (Interpreted frame)
>    - com.wily.isengard.postofficehub.link.v1.IncomingRouteConnector.receiveIncomingMessages(com.wily.isengard.postofficehub.link.v1.IsengardObjectInputStream)
>   @bci=18, line=170 (Interpreted frame)
>    - com.wily.isengard.postofficehub.link.v1.IncomingRouteConnector.doTask()
>   @bci=32, line=89 (Interpreted frame)
>    - com.wily.isengard.util.thread.AThreadedExecutable.run() @bci=27, line=192 (Interpreted frame)

The socketRead0 call is blocking io in native code. It will not return until a byte is read or, if the socket read timeout has been set, it times out. It cannot be interrupted. If you have any control over the creation of the Socket, it is important to [set the timeout](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/Socket.html#setSoTimeout%28int%29).

Comment: Thanks for the info. Did you mean to say it is a blocking IO call?  What you described sounds to me like it is blocking in the native code.

Comment: Yes, I did mean blocking. I have edited the comment.